# Join tables to concat every possible combination

Tags: mysql, join

I have two mysql tables. One with article numbers and one with variants numbers.
No I want to join the tables so have a result table with every possible article/variant combination.
For example:

Article numbers table:

```
+-----------+-------------+
| ArticleNo | ArticleName |
+-----------+-------------+
|      0001 | Product 1   |
|      0002 | Product 2   |
|      0003 | Product 3   |
+-----------+-------------+
```

Variants numbers table:

```
+-----------+-------------+
| VariantNo | VariantName |
+-----------+-------------+
|      1001 | Variant 1   |
|      1002 | Variant 2   |
|      1003 | Variant 3   |
+-----------+-------------+
```

Result table:

```
+----------+---------------------+
| ResultNo |     ResultName      |
+----------+---------------------+
| 00011001 | Product 1 Variant 1 |
| 00011002 | Product 1 Variant 2 |
| 00011003 | Product 1 Variant 3 |
| 00021001 | Product 2 Variant 1 |
| 00021002 | Product 2 Variant 2 |
| 00021003 | Product 2 Variant 3 |
| 00031001 | Product 3 Variant 1 |
| 00031002 | Product 3 Variant 2 |
| 00031003 | Product 3 Variant 3 |
+----------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write Directly:

```
SELECT  CONCAT(a.ArticleNo,v.VariantNo) as ResultNo, 
CONCAT(a.ArticleName,v.VariantName) as ResultName 
FROM Article a,Variants v
```

It will produce Cross Join

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a Cartesian product.  In SQL this is provided through `CROSS JOIN`:

```
select concat(a.ArticleNo, v.VariantNo) as ResultNo,
       concat_ws(' ', a.ArticleName, v.VariantName) as ResultName
from articles a cross join
     variants v
order by a.ArticleName, v.VariantName;
```

Answer (score -1):

I think [this](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/advance-query-in-mysql/mysql-cross-join.php) is what you are looking for. This kind of operation generates Cartesian Product. To solve your problem you should apply this query from link above and it should look like this:

```
select concat(ArticleNo,VariantNo ) as ResultNo ,
concat(ArticleName,VariantName) as  ResultName 
from Article 
cross join Variants
```